# A Few Questions About the Global Object

Tags: javascript

A global object is an object that always exists in the global scope. In JavaScript there is always a global object defined.

Can there be more than one global object? Why do people say Window is a global object when MDN doesnt say this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by MDN doesn't say this: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object): *The window object is the Global Object in the Browser*

Comment: `Can there be more than one global object?` no. Javascript is a programming language that has no mind reading capability - if there were more than one Global object, how would the JS engine "know" which one "you mean"

Comment: @MarkMeyer whoops i read that but had forgotten about that part

Comment: @JaromandaX ok thank you for the help!

Comment: @JaromandaX why do people call the document object a global object?

Comment: well, I guess `window` is global, so anything, like `window.document` is global ... it's A global object, not THE global object :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every browser window has a single top level `Window` object routinely referred to as *global object*. The global object is accessible via `window` variable.
The object exposes a number of properties, most importantly `document` which is also an object, methods, and events.
A developer may define (via script) variables (`var`) and `function`s  which automatically become properties and methods of `window` (*global*) object (provided they are declared on top (global) level).
For example, an expression `var a = 1;` declares a variable named `a` (and assign numeric value to it). This variable is accessible by its name (`a`) and as well as `window.a` and `window['a']`.
The reference to the global `window` object can be omitted so `window.a = 2;` and `a = 2;` are equivalent (but not `['a'] = 2;` which is syntax error).
Also note that *global `window` object* belongs to the browser window, not to javascript. The browser only *expose* it to *Scripting Engine*.

This is `javascript` basics.

I hope this explanation clears a little your confusion.