# What are the types of global objects `window` and `document`?

Tags: javascript, dom

In JavaScript DOM, there are global objects `window` and `document`.

What is the type of `window`? Is it [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)?

What is the type of `document`? `HTMLDocument` (see the diagram below) or [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)?

By type, I mean either `interface` in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model, or `class` in JavaScript: The Definitive Guide

[image]

Comment: Easy to check: `window instanceof Window` returns `true` :).

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55545105/a-few-questions-about-the-global-object/55545547#55545547

Comment: You answer is in the first two paragraphs of the link you posted: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In JavaScript DOM, there are global objects window and document.

No, not really. The `window` is part of the Browser Object Model (BOM), not the [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction). And the `document` is not a Global object, it's a property of the Global `window` object. The reason you can access it as just `document` is not because `document` is Global, it's because `window` is and because of the way the JavaScript [Scope Chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385835/invocation-context-and-execution-context-in-javascript-are-we-talking-of-th/41386097#41386097) works, omitting `window` just means that it will ultimately find `document` in the Global `window` object.

The "Core" Document Object Model is a generic API for working with XML or HTML documents and because it can be used in both kinds, the `document` object is not specific to an HTML or XML document.

The graphic that you are showing refers to a variant of the Document Object Model, called the ***HTML DOM***, which takes into account elements and attributes that are specific to HTML documents, and so yes, in that graphic, `HTMLDocument` implements the `Document` interface and that means that an HTMLDocument is a type of document, but it is still also implementing the `Node` interface.

Now finally, we have to address types vs. instances. In JavaScript there is no `window` or `document` "type", there are "objects", which `window` and `document` are. Objects though come in many different varieties and `window` is an instance of a `Window` object, while `document` is an instance of a `Document` object:

```js
console.log(typeof window);  // The window is a type of object
console.log(window instanceof Window);  // Particularly a Window object

// You can often find out what interface the object implements
// by just logging it cast as a string.
console.log(window.toString());
console.log(document.toString());
```

Comment: "a global object" usually means "an object held by a global variable", it doesn't refer to "the Global object (`window`)".

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but OP doesn't use that terminology. OP specifically says: *In JavaScript DOM, there are global objects `window` and `document`*. so it's clear that OP is referring to *the* Global object (`window`).

Comment: Not clear to me: he mentions the `window` and `document` global variables and refers to the objects they hold

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to ask for the specific type of an object directly, instead of guessing and checking by `window instanceof Window`?

Comment: @Tim I've updated my answer to show how you can do this by checking the string version of the object.